# javascript: How can I convert a string number to number in Javascript without remove any number after dots?

Tags: javascript, string, numbers, double, converters

I have a string number like this:
price = "200.000"
I would like to convert this value to the number: 200.000
How can I do that? I tried to convert this value with parseInt(), but it remove number after the dot.

Comment: `200.000` is equivalent to `200`

Comment: the short answer is ... you can't ... the long answer is, you really can't

Comment: What is to.fixed?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you mean `200.000` represents 200 thousand, you should remove all non-decimal characters before you `parseInt` by using `replace`. And if you want to display in that format, use `toLocaleString` to output it that way (which is `de-DE`)

```js
let numberString = '20.000.000';

let number = parseInt(numberString.replace(/[^\d]/g, ''));

console.log('Your number is: ' + number);

console.log('Your formated number is: ' + number.toLocaleString('de-DE'));
```

Comment: i understand your way. but how about i put another input in there?. Like 20.000.000 as input? what am I expected is output in the same result as input. for example, if in put is "20.000" => output is 20.000. if input is "20.000.000", output is 20.000.000

Comment: @NguyenNgocHai Oh, I misunderstood that, I thought `200.000` literal means `200`. I updated the answer, please check.